# Reducing the Hardcoded if statement to be more Dynamic

Tags: php, if-statement

i have a radio button which could be selected on an infinite amount of rows as it adds a new row everytime the first one is completed, the user then selects which one they want to be the primary number which set it as a value "1" or "2" etc..

my issue is if the user where to enter more than 8 phone numbers my code would be obsolete i was wondering what the best way to do this was :

```
if ($Details['MakePrimary'] == 1){
    $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][0]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][0]['mainNumber']; 
} else if ($Details['MakePrimary'] == 2){
    $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][1]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][1]['mainNumber']; 
} else if ($paymentDetails['MakePrimary'] == 3){
    $Customer->StdCode = $Details['phoneNumber'][2]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][2]['mainNumber'];   
} else if ($Details['MakePrimary'] == 4){
    $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][3]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][3]['mainNumber'];
} else if ($paymentDetails['MakePrimary'] == 5){
    $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][4]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][4]['mainNumber']; 
} else if ($Details['MakePrimary'] == 6){
    $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][5]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][5]['mainNumber'];   
} else if ($Details['MakePrimary'] == 7){
    $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][6]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][6]['mainNumber'];   
} else if ($Details['MakePrimary'] == 8){
    $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][7]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][7]['mainNumber'];                               
} else {
    $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][8]['Code']; 
    $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][8]['mainNumber'];
}
```

Comment: use it as a key, then assign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this :

```
$index = $paymentDetails['MakePrimary'] - 1;
$voipCustomer->StdCode = $paymentDetails['phoneNumber'][$index]['stdCode'];
$voipCustomer->Number = $paymentDetails['phoneNumber'][$index]['mainNumber'];
```

Comment: nice :) , and i promise, i did not copy your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $Customer->Code = $Details['phoneNumber'][$Details['MakePrimary']-1]['Code']; 
 $Customer->Number = $Details['phoneNumber'][$Details['MakePrimary']-1]['mainNumber'];
```

Comment: Thanks both helped me out  :)